# How can I rollback my GParted version?

Tags: software-installation, gparted, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with GParted 0.18. However, it seems to be inferior to previous iterations of it because it **crashes** **every single time** I try to resize a FAT32 partition or when I create a new partition on an unallocated block of memory. I have not tried it with NTFS or ext4. When I run it through the terminal as superuser, it displays a Segmentation Fault as it crashes.

This was not the case with the previous versions of GParted such as the default one with 12.04 and 13.04, where I was able to perfectly able to partition my USB drive. Is there any way I can get the old versions (0.12 or 0.16) and install them on my 14.04 build?

Comment: Many problems are fixed in newer versions of GParted.  The most recent version is 0.19.1 which fixes some crash issues.  One way to use this version is by booting from media containing [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) - most recent version 0.19.1-4.

Comment: GParted live does work perfectly. That said, I can't find any way to upgrade/downgrade the version on my ubuntu! How can I do it?

Comment: excellent question, and what a complete fail on the distro! Wheres the support on this?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid it has been fixed in the newer versions of ubuntu, but if you're stuck on the LTS release without getting updates for GParted, you maybe out of luck.

Comment: What is the exact version of your gparted?

Answer (score 0):

17 January 2020

This answer is related due to the expiration of support for `Trusty Tahr` last May.

It is slightly different in that I decided I needed to reinstall `gparted` because I was getting segmentation faults when I tried to 'check & repair' a `FAT32` partition created by `gparted`, so I issued the commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove gparted
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

The problem, as I understand it, is that `apt-get update` revised the local copies of the repository indices, indicating that `apt` should get `gparted` version `0.24.0-1` which is an upgraded version in the repositories and is the extended support version.  The problem is, you have to pay for extended support, and normal people simply upgrade to a newer long term release instead.  Therefore, you get the now familiar errors when apt tries to fetch the binary:

```
Err http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps gparted i386 0.24.0-1~getdeb1 Temporary failure resolving 'archive.getdeb.net'
W: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/g/gparted/gparted_0.24.0-1~getdeb1_i386.deb Temporary failure resolving 'archive.getdeb.net'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

A partial solution is to go to the `gparted` launchpad ppa:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted
```

Scoll down and click on the triangle next to `Trusty Tahr 0.18.0-1` which is actually a little newer than the last LTS supported version of `gparted`.  Then scroll down under the heading package files and select a `.deb` file for your machine and click on it to download.

Now issue the command:

```
dpkg -i <your downloaded file>
```

This worked for me with the i386 architecture, the GUI starts and looks normal and gives information on installed volumes and partitions.  There are some font and format changes in the modal dialogs to emphasize warnings.  There are three caveats:

- There are error messages in the console on start up about `source id xx not found when attempting to remove it` where 'xx' is a small integer.  These are `GLib` errors of the sort I have often seen over the years.  They are only visible when you start programs by command line.  They never have seemed to have any effect on function.
- When I format and check a `FAT16` partition on the thumb drive, the check tells me it has not been formatted correctly, with sizes differing from 'correct' as follows:

  - `cluster size            16k ;   16k expected`
  - `number of clusters    64238 ; 64239 expected`
  - `FAT size        256 sectors ;   251 expected`
  - If I select ignore, it offers to convert to `FAT32`, if I say no, `gparted` crashes with `malloc(): memory corruption: ...`
  - If I select ignore and convert, `gparted` crashes with `Segmentation fault`
- When I format and check a `FAT32` partition on the thumb drive,`gparted` reports the file system has `188686 clusters ; 188588 expected`.   Selecting ignore causes a crash with `malloc(): memory corruption: ...`.

In summary, the problems seem to be within `gparted`, `libparted` specifically during the expand to fill partition phase, and the slightly newer version merely giving more informative error messages instead of a rude segmentation fault (except in the one case).

If I format the thumb drive with `gnome-disks` instead, no option for `FAT16` is given and formatting results in `FAT32`.  If you choose custom format and enter `fat16`, an error informing you that `FAT16` is not supported results.  If I then check the `gnome-disks` `FAT32` with `gparted` it crashes with `malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: ...`.

If I use `gnome-disks` and select the non-quick option (fill with zeros), and then check with `gparted`, it crashes with `free(): invalid next size (normal): ...`.

These formatted partitions seem to work OK for storing data, even though `gparted` can't check them.  An installation of `Clonezilla` will not boot, which is a very handy tool for backing up prior to deleting the whole installation and installing the newest LTS release.

Now there are three possibilities:

- The obvious one is that `gparted` can't check a `FAT` partition correctly.
- It is also possible that `gparted` can't format a `FAT` partition, but it is unlikely that both `gparted` and `gnome-disks` are crippled, unless they use the same commandline tools.
- It is possible there is some subtle defect in the thumb drive that makes it minimally functional.  Perhaps it requires a `FAT16` partition, which `gnome-disks` can't create, and `gparted` can't create correctly.

Lastly I performed the `Clonezilla` installation on another thumb drive of unknown provenance, using the `FAT16` partition that was already on it, presumably installed by the manufacturer.  That worked.  This does not clearly make the first thumb drive guilty.  I need to find a `Windows` machine and reformat the first thumb drive.  If the issues persist, it is the drive.  If that fixes things, it is a condemnation of `gparted`'s ability to format a `FAT` partition, which is a little ridiculous for any software less than 10 years old, given the pervasive presence of these formats on bootable media.  Even `FAT12` compatibility is required by the `UEFI` specification.

To answer criticisms of the original query more directly, there is nothing wrong with downloading and installing a program manually.  You do, however, enter into "dependency hell".  In `Windows`, programs are monolithic and self-contained, and therefore bloated and large.  The virtue is, they just work (well, mostly; an OS upgrade can break things).  With a package manager, programs are small and have dependencies shared with other programs.  If you see to it that all of the correct dependencies are installed, then things work.

The difficulty is, upgrades to a dependency can break a program dependent on it, so the program dependent on it needs to be upgraded.  Normally the package manager and the packagers resolve this hell for you.  If you try to go backward, you may also need to roll back libraries, which likely will break other programs.  If support ends, ideally the repositories are frozen, so whatever bugs remain, remain, but things are still usable.  If `Canonical` corrupts the repositories with inaccessible updates for paid extended support, then you are shit out of luck.

As for upgrading to a newer version of `gparted`, you can get one from the launchpad ppa, but now you enter "dependency hell" in the other direction, where the new version depends on newer libraries, and those newer libraries, if installed, likely will break other programs.  Worse still, if you do this, you will be unable to reinstall from the repositories since `Canonical` has corrupted them with extended support that is inaccessible.

As a final remark, it is a bit odious that `Canonical` uses the `apt` interface for its paid extended support.  This apparently precludes continued use of the previously supported but now obsolete repositories for software installation, as they are corrupted by updates that can not be accessed without fee.  This makes life quite a bit more difficult for those of us that are a little slow to go through the onerous process of backup, wiping the disk, and freshly installing a newer release.  I have found in the past that upgrading across releases never works well, it is better to start over with a clean disk.

This state of affairs certainly violates the spirit of the `GPL`.  It also violates the letter of the `GPL` in one way.  `Canonical` is, of course, at liberty to corrupt its repositories instead of freezing them, odious as that is, after all, they own the repositories.  The practice certainly casts a pall on `Canonical`'s open source reputation.  But to cause a `Debian` package manager, namely `apt` to fail with mysterious error messages, in my opinion, violates the `GPL`.  `Canonical` should create a fork of `apt`, call it `ept` or better yet `inept`, that exclusively processes extended maintenance updates, while freezing the base repositories until phase out, for the benefit of the large individual user base that has given `Canonical` its fame.

I think my next system is going to be a pure `Debian` installation.  I've really had enough of `Canonical`.